# Deleted password under Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, login, password, passwd

I have a very serious problem. I deleted my password with 
`passwd -d user`, and now I can't log in to my account. I thought this would be a way to enter my account without entering the password by every login. Is there a standard UNIX/SOLARIS password to enter my account?

Answer (score 2):

Login as root, and use

```
passwd yourusername
```

to set a new password for the user (change `yourusername` to the appropriate name).

If you, for whatever reason, can not login as root, you may need to put the system into single user mode ("runlevel S") and issue the command from there.  The steps for doing this is described in [the official Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36801/fvzqr.html) and, for x86 platforms (not SPARC), boils down to

1. `reboot -p` (hmmm... this assumes that you are root)

   - "If the system displays the Press Any Key to Reboot prompt, press any key to reboot the system. Or, you can also use the Reset button at this prompt."
   - "If the system is shut down, turn the system on with the power switch."
2. "When the GRUB menu is displayed, select the boot entry that you want to modify, then type `e` to edit that entry."
3. "Using the arrow keys, navigate to the `$multiboot` line, then type `–s` at the end of the line."
4. "To exit the GRUB edit menu and boot the entry you just edited, press <kbd>Control-X</kbd>. If you are not using a serial console on a system with UEFI firmware, pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> also boots the entry."
5. "Verify that the system is at run level S." ... with `who -r`.
6. "Perform the maintenance task that required the change to run level S." (this is where you use `passwd yourusername`).
7. "Reboot the system."

The above is untested as I do not have a Solaris system available.

Answer (score 0):

Unless "PASSREQ=NO" is set in /etc/default/login, you'd not be able to login with out a password--it's set to YES by default as well as reco'd.

You'll have to have a SA reset your password.  If you're the only SA, you'll need to boot off media, mount the root pool, and manually edit the shadow or /etc/default/login file to get back in.

Another option if you're the only SA is that if you have any other boot environments (BE's), you could boot to an ABE, and from there mount the current BE to modify the shadow or /etc/default/login file to get back in on the current BE.